# If $\dim L(V,V)$ is finite; then $\dim V$ is finite?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a question, Let $L(V,V) = \{f:V \to V:$ $f$ is linear map $\}$. If $\dim L(V,V) = n \leq \infty$ 
then $\dim V < \infty$??

I know that if $\dim V =n$  then $\dim L(V,V) = n²$, but the otherwise is true?

Comment: If $V$ were infinite dimensional, then there would exists an infinite linearly independent set $(v_n)$ and the functions $f_n$ defined to be zero outside the span of $v_n$ and the identity on this span are clearly linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ has a basis $\{v_\alpha\}$, then the projections
\begin{align*}
v_\alpha^*(v_\beta) &= \begin{cases}
v_\alpha & \text{if } \beta = \alpha; \\
0 & \text{if } \beta \not = \alpha
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
are linearly independent elements of $L(V, V)$. If $L(V, V)$ is finite-dimensional, then $\{v_\alpha\}$ must be a finite set.

Answer (score 1):

Supppose $V$ is infinite dimensional, and let $\{e_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in J}$ be a basis. Then, $\{e^*_{\alpha\beta}\}_{\alpha,\beta\in J}$ defined by

$$e^*_{\alpha\beta}(e_{j})=e_{\beta}\ \text{if}\ j=\alpha\ \text{and}\  e^*_{\alpha\beta}(e_{j})=0\ \text{if}\  j\neq \alpha$$

is a linearly independent set in $L(V,V)$ of infinite cardinality, which is a contradiction.